# raspberry pi 3V LED. What resistor to use?

Tags: led, raspberry-pi

I will connect this button with a 3V LED to RP3. what resistor should I be using ? Do not know the amperage of the LED.

https://www.amazon.co.uk/sourcing-map-Momentary-Button-Mounting/dp/B07FYSR7Y7/ref=sr_1_6?keywords=Push%2BButton%2BSwitch%2B3v&qid=1565432578&s=diy&sr=1-6&th=1

Comment: You need to know the LED's forward voltage and current to properly select an LED. If the vendor or manufacturer does not provide that information **buy somewhere else**, because a reputable vendor always will.

Comment: You  could ask Ascot City, who supply the item to Amazon, for details of the LED.

Comment: If you have to buy this one only then I would suggest to start with a 100 ohm resistor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to buy this one only then I would suggest to start with a 100 ohm resistor, it might not please the eyes but from there you can try tweaking. Anything higher than 100 ohms would work too but the LED might appear way dimmer. Depending on the forward voltage the LED(if greater than 3.3V) might never turn on also.

Assuming 3V as forward voltage of LED, the remaining voltage will be 0.3 V.. the sum is equal to 3.3 V (RP3).

So, The current will be 0.3 V/100 ohms And is about 3 mA. You can slightly reduce the resistor value for brighter LED. Do not exceed GPIO current limit of the RP3.

**Second option** for brighter LED:

You can also use a BJT and drive the base with the GPIO and drive the when te LED with a series resistor connected to 5V available on Pi.

Comment: For the exact current limit you have to read the datasheet.. or share the part number of the processor present on the RP3

Comment: That is the Maximum current limit for the LED. You can size the resistor so that the current us less than the LED spec. Current. What does the datasheet  of BCM2837 states as maximum supported GPIO output current?

Comment: http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/microcontroller-projects/raspberry-pi/gpio-pin-electrical-specifications  current limit is upto 16 mA.. I wouldn't drive more than 5-8 mA using that as the excess current may lead to heating up of the chip. Choose a value and try ..my recommendation: 100 ohms upto 56 ohms. Please try and see

Comment: better to start from 56 ohms